# Allow access to operation only one user at the time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I have ASP.NET Core application which communicates with web api.
There is an business operation involving a few steps (do sth on one page, go to next and next). This multi-step operation is being done in context of one element.

So let's say you have a list of *some business objects* and your task is to accept *object 3* from this list. Accepting is our multistep operation and if I am currently *accepting object 3* no one else should be able to enter accepting operation for *object 3*. When I finish operation, it should be unlocked.
Hope the problem is understandable.

We don't want very time-consuming solution, the simplest idea was to create a database table which indicates when user starts operation, it saves id of the object and id of the user and automatcally remove itself after for example 5 minutes, if someone else want to access operation we check if it is blocked for this object. But it is kind of hacky and not very clean (what if user will go for a coffee and continue operation after 10 minutes?)

I'm looking for a better way to implement this kind of behaviour and appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 3):

If I were to implement that behavior, I'll also use database, but kinda different way. I'll make a table of *objects* (*object 3* is one of its row), adding a column for `UserId`, boolean `OnProcess` (to mark if the object is on process or not) and timestamp for `StartProcess`.

For a user to be able to enter the operation, run query like:

```
UPDATE Objects SET UserId = <CurrentUser>, StartProcess = <NOW>, OnProcess = true
OUTPUT Object.Id
WHERE Object.Id == 3 AND 
    (
        OnProcess == false
        OR ( OnProcess == true AND UserId == <CurrentUser> )
        OR ( StartProcess <is more than 15 minutes ago>)
    )
```

disclaimer: the query above is not an executable query, but it should be clear enough to understand what it does.

With the query above, the `Object.Id` will be returned when:

- the object is not being processed by another user
- the object is being processed by the `CurrentUser` itself, also resetting the `StartProcess` (some kind of sliding behavior). This way, if `CurrentUser` AFK for a given time (but not exceeding the threshold time) and comes back, he/she can comfortably continue the operation
- the object is not being processed for the last 15 minutes. This is actually the threshold that I mention in previous point. As for how long (15 minutes in my example), it is really up to you.

If the `Object.Id` is returned for a user, then he/she are able to enter the operation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the solution involves creating table of objects on which users can start multistep operation? The case is that I do have already such table but it contains around 0.5M records, so I'm not sure if adding a column to it would be such a great idea

Comment: How many columns currently do your table has? I don't think adding 3 more columns will be a problem except your table already has hundreds and many select * in your code

Comment: Well it has 16 columns, maybe you're right but wouldn't it be a better idea to create small new table used just for this purpose?

Comment: the query in my answer is assuming that it doesnt have to worry about the row's availability. If you create a new smaller table, then you'll have to ensure the row 's exist before any user can start. Depending on your whole application, it can be trivial or hard to implement. I guess only you can decide which is better, create small table or adding 3 more columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a semaphore. The `lock` keyword is the most basic of semaphores, but you can also use `Semaphore`/`SemaphoreSlim`, which provide the ability to do things like rate-limiting, whereas `lock` will literally gate one op at a time. However, your goal is to gate one op at a time, *for a particular resource*, which makes `SemaphoreSlim` a better choice, specifically a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>`.

You'll need a class with singleton lifetime (one instance for the entire life of the application). There, you'll add an ivar:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _semaphores = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
```

Then, you'll add the following code around the operation you want to gate:

```
var semaphore = _semaphores.GetOrAdd("object3", _ => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
await semaphore.WaitAsync();

// do something

semaphore.Release();
```

The `"object3"` there is obviously just a placeholder. You'll want to use whatever makes sense (ID, etc.) - something that uniquely identifies the particular resource you're gating. This then will only hold operations for that particular resource if there's an existing operation on that particular resource. A different resource would get its own semaphore and thus its own gate.

Comment: It does not seem like an in-memory solution would be fault tolerant or scale out in any way. If this operation is business critical, a database-based mechanism is probably a hard requirement.

Comment: First, the code presented here doesn't have to be literally in the app. It could be in a separate console app, a service, etc. Second, the OP didn't specify that it had to be a persistent lock. It just needs to prevent two operations on the same "object" as the same time, which if the app goes down, then no operations are happening on any objects. A database approach may give you persistence across app restarts, but it exponentially compounds concurrency headaches.

Comment: You'd need to prepopulate the database with all possible objects so that you could do an optimistic update, and then have a retry policy to reattempt on update failure. Inserts are a no-go for the most part.

Comment: I'm a little baffled by your comment, but maybe I'm mistaken. I was assuming that this enforcement would have to take place on the web server, which could be in a server farm, or subjected to app pool recycles. In both of these cases the locking primitive could exist simultaneously in two or more app domains and therefore not do its job properly.

Comment: A web farm might be a situation where you'd want to externalize it. The web app can just schedule it on the external process, and then you'd still just have one ingress/egress point, just async. There's frankly lots of ways to mitigate any of the issues you mentioned. The database approach is just problematic start to finish no matter what you do.

Comment: Still baffled. Don't know what you mean by "the external process." The architecture is several instances of a .NET core app talking to a single web API, as I read it-- very simple, very common. I have no idea where a console program or additional process would sit in that environment. Perhaps we just need to agree to disagree.

Comment: Actually, I agree with @JohnWu that's not the case I'm looking for